# How to put logon username trigger?

Tags: oracle, ddl, triggers

can anyone help me with this one!

I would like to have a trigger in Oracle, which finds out the user's Windows logon name.

The user name should be added in to table "Product" (column "username"), after insertion of other data in the table "Product".

Thanks in advance for any help you are able to provide.

Comment: If the user is logging in through a web/windows application, then it won't be possible and you'd have to send the username through exclusively in the update/insert statements, because otherwise the username you will pick up is that of what the web/windows application uses to connect to Oracle with

Comment: The OS username that is available in Oracle (e.g. through `sys_context('userenv', 'os_user')`) is an information provided by the client application. You can not trust that. I can log in claiming to be the OS user "Larry.Ellison" or "None Of Your Business"

Answer (score 0):

How to make one trigger that operates on all tables? Otherwise, I got a lot of triggers in the database.In SQL Developer can be selected only one table. I wish one trigger that takes username information and add's it to that table I insert data at that moment.